# how to select one of many images from a group of images (cycled with prev/ next arrows) and upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a  script which lets user search and find images from a url. I got it, and can get the urls of the images (one or more) in an array.  I want to show one image at a time, with `<<prev` and `next>>` buttons and provide an upload button in a form.

Any hints on how to implement an inline slideshow, and upload the image that user has selected?

eg:

```
<div id="imgSelected">

  <img src="img1.jpg">
  <img src="img2.jpg">
</div>

<form>
  <input type='hidden' value='img1.jpg>
  <input type=text' placeholder='title'>
  <input type='submit' value='upload'>
</form>
```

I can use something like jquery cycle (http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/)  to show the next/ prev buttons and cycle the image. but when that happens, how can I update the value in the form for the image src?

Comment: Have a variable to store the current index and use the < > to increment decrement the array index, each time retrieving the url at that index of the array, but becareful not to index negative or greater than the size of the array.

Comment: So do you fetch the URLs and generate `<img>` tags for each, expecting to hide/show based on clicking "prev" and "next"?

Comment: @ianpgall yes. So there will only be one image shown at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EpjYe/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var all_images = $("#images").children(".image");
    var cur_selected = all_images.filter(".image-selected");
    checkNoneSelected(all_images, cur_selected);

    $("#prev").on("click", function () {
        var all_images = $("#images").children(".image");
        var cur_selected = all_images.filter(".image-selected");

        if (!checkNoneSelected(all_images, cur_selected)) {
            cur_selected = moveImage(all_images, cur_selected, -1, 0);
            $("#hidden1").val(cur_selected.prop("src"));
        }
    });

    $("#next").on("click", function () {
        var all_images = $("#images").children(".image");
        var cur_selected = all_images.filter(".image-selected");

        if (!checkNoneSelected(all_images, cur_selected)) {
            cur_selected = moveImage(all_images, cur_selected, 1, all_images.length-1);
            $("#hidden1").val(cur_selected.prop("src"));
        }
    });
});

function checkNoneSelected(all_images, cur_selected) {
    if (cur_selected.length === 0) {
        all_images.first().addClass("image-selected");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function moveImage(all_images, cur_selected, direction, end_pos) {
    var cur_index = all_images.index(cur_selected);

    if (cur_index !== end_pos) {
        var new_index = cur_index + direction;
        cur_selected.removeClass("image-selected");
        cur_selected = $(all_images[new_index]);
        cur_selected.addClass("image-selected");
    }

    return cur_selected;
}
```

Of course you'd have to use consistent `id` and `class` attributes, as mine is only an example.

Comment: Thanks, fiddle looks just what I was looking for. will check this out soon on my script and update.

Comment: @aVC No problem. Yeah, I'm sure there's many ways to do what you want, but this is just an option. If you notice in the fiddle though, the `<input type="hidden">`'s value is updated to the currently selected image's URL on change, which is what I think you wanted.